# setting up drush AFTER drupal multisite installed

Tags: drush, 8, multi-sites

new to drupal and even newer to drush. godaddy shared hosting, I manually setup drupal 8.x multisite where one site is the host account and the rest are subdomains to it. (I didn't use the cpanel install wizard)

I just ssh'd in and setup drush but now I don't understand how to configure it to see all my sites. all the info I've seen relates to setting up drupal using drush, not configuring drush with an existing installation, especially multisite.

do I need to create aliases? any help is appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drush does not need configuration, as long as you run commands from the relevant site folder such as `www-root/drupal-core/sites/mysite` it will work.

Do check that your version of drush is compatible with Drupal 8 though.

Comment: you are correct! so are you saying in order for me to use the alias, I have to use drush in the drupal sites folder? I thought aliases were so you can easily run drush commands from any directory, even remotely? I successfully did drush --root=/xxx --uri=http:xxx status in my home directory so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong

Comment: Yes, I believe you can set aliases so you don't need to change directory to use drush, but as you can see, it isn't necessary.

Comment: yes it's necessary, I have more than one site I need to administer on the same host. I'll never be able to effectively work remotely via ssh if I have to type out the whole path etc

Comment: Apologies, I meant 'necessary for drush to function' not 'necessary for effective administration'.

Comment: This should be useful:
https://www.acquia.com/blog/leverage-drush-7-drupal-8